# Converting php aes256 decrypt function to typescript gives

Tags: php, typescript

I have a PHP aes256 decrypt function I am trying to convert to typescript in ionic 5 but I am faced with the following error using md5:

> This expression is not callable.   Type 'any[]' has no call
> signatures.

**PHP decrypt function:**

```
function decrypt(string $jsonStr, string $passphrase)
    {
        $json = json_decode($jsonStr, true);
        $salt = hex2bin($json["s"]);
        $iv = hex2bin($json["iv"]);
        $ct = base64_decode($json["ct"]);
        $concatedPassphrase = $passphrase . $salt;
        $md5 = [];
        $md5[0] = md5($concatedPassphrase, true);
        $result = $md5[0];
        for ($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++) {
            $md5[$i] = md5($md5[$i - 1] . $concatedPassphrase, true);
            $result .= $md5[$i];
        }
        $key = substr($result, 0, 32);
        $data = openssl_decrypt($ct, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, true, $iv);
        return json_decode($data, true);
    }
```

**Typescript converted:**

```
async dcrypt(data: string, passphrase: string){

    const json = JSON.parse(data);
    const salt = decode(json["s"]);
    const iv = decode(json["iv"]);
    const ct = decode(json["ct"]);
    const concatedPassphrase = passphrase + salt;
    const md5 = [];
    md5[0] = md5(concatedPassphrase, true);
    let result = md5[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
      md5[i] = md5(md5[i - 1] + concatedPassphrase, true);
      result += md5[i];
    }
    const key = result.substr(0, 32);
    const importedKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
      'raw',
      new Uint8Array(key),
      {
        name: 'AES-CBC'
      },
      false,
      ['decrypt']
    );
    const data = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
      {
        name: 'AES-CBC',
        iv: new Uint8Array(iv)
      },
      importedKey,
      new Uint8Array(ct)
    );
    return JSON.parse(new TextDecoder().decode(data));
    

  }
```

Both md5 functions: `md5(concatedPassphrase, true)` && `md5(md5[i - 1] + concatedPassphrase, true)` are giving me the following error:

> This expression is not callable.   Type 'any[]' has no call
> signatures.

How can I resolve this issue using `md5`?

Comment: It might help to do `const md5: string[] = []` so that TypeScript thinks the array is an array of `string`s, not of `any`s.

Comment: @siride That changes nothing. The error still persists.

Comment: I see the problem. You are using `md5` as a local variable name and also as a function. Your local variable should be renamed to something like `md5array`.

Comment: You'll still want to apply my other change, though, to avoid extraneous `any`s.